# Customizing jQuery UI Slider height & width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slider

When customizing the height/width of the jQuery UI Slider (and handle), the handle will now slide too far left (off of slider). Is there a recommended way of going about doing this?

Here's a fiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/w7A4k/

I didn't see anything in the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) for this, and I'm using a very basic setup:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    max: 100,
    min: 0
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HF6Sm/)</kbd>

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    height: 15px;
    width: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px; //add this
}
```

---

To put the slider inside the bar add `padding-left: 5px;`

Comment: Your example goes to the left much more than to the right (for a whole handle width)

Answer (score 1):

Unit size of JQuery UI Slider is in `em`. Therefore slider size is  relative to its font size.

- Change the font size of slider div to handle slider HEIGHT.
- Change the container width of slider to handle slider WIDTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    function home_page_banner_height(selector) {   
        var wind_widht = $( window ).width();   
        var req_height = ( (banner_height / banner_width) * 100 );   
        //banner_height is height of item div of carousel and banner_width is width of item div of caousel 

        var calculate_height = (wind_widht / 100) * req_height;
        $('.v_center_con .v_center_inner').height(calculate_height);     
        $(selector).height(calculate_height);     
    }

    home_page_banner_height('.banner_con .item');     

    $(window).resize(function() {     
        home_page_banner_height('.banner_con .item');           
        //this function will make your slider responsive for all screen sizes
    });
});
```